# OpenCV nMatToBitmap Assertion Failed

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm getting the following errors using some generic functions within OpenCV for Android

```
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/cv::error()(6658): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /home/oleg/sources/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 107
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/org.opencv.android.Utils(6658): nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /home/oleg/sources/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:107: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/CameraBridge(6658): Mat type: Mat [ 144*192*CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1024c0, dataAddr=0x44783010 ]
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/CameraBridge(6658): Bitmap type: 384*288
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/CameraBridge(6658): Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: /home/oleg/sources/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:107: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

I'm not sure if this is the error itself or if it's caused by another problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The assertion error is telling you that one or more of the following tests is failing:

```
src.dims == 2
info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows
info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols
```

I'm guessing `info` contains the dimensions of the destination bitmap. In that case, either your source Mat is not 2 dimensions or the dimensions of the destination bitmap don't match the dimensions of the source Mat.

These two lines

```
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/CameraBridge(6658): Mat type: Mat [ 144*192*CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1024c0, dataAddr=0x44783010 ]
12-05 21:08:55.486: E/CameraBridge(6658): Bitmap type: 384*288
```

suggest that your Mat is 144x192 and your bitmap is 384x288. It looks like one is portrait and the other landscape plus your bitmap is twice the resolution of your Mat.

Comment: Could anybody suggest a way to scale the the Mat to be the same size of the Bitmap? I'm having the same problem but I'm still learning OpenCV so not enough skills with it...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions are best posted as questions, not as comments to answers. Be sure to include a little code showing what you've tried so far and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are completely right. I just thought that because is tightly related to this question could be posted here. Thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: try with change:
Size size = new Size(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight());

Comment: In this error, the Mat dimensions are reported as height * width, while the Bitmap dims are width * height. So in OP's case, the orientations are both the same, it's just the resolutions that are mismatched. In my error, my Mat was 1024*768*CV_8UC4 vs. Bitmap 1024*768, which stumped me until I uncovered the inconsistency.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I'll provide an answer instead:

When working with the 'onCameraFrame' method - this assertion is thrown if the 'mat' you return doesn't match the size of the frame used to display the output.

In other words - if you're resizing for some sort of processing, make sure to return it to the original size before throwing it back to the display.

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame 
inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    Mat resizeImage = new Mat();
    Size sz = new Size(800, 600); // Scale up to 800x600
    Imgproc.resize(mRgba, resizeImage, sz);

    // Do some sort of processing here on resized image.

    Mat afterResize = new Mat();
    Size szAfter = new Size(640, 480); // Scale back down to 640x480 (original dim.)
    Imgproc.resize(resizeImage, afterResize, szAfter);

    return afterResize;
}
```

Comment: Someone else already specified my answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970551/opencv-resize-failing